# Default graphql queries are not listing in ChromeiQL

Tags: magento2, graphql

Hello I am exploring Graphql currently and testing the magento's default graphql APIs but in ChromeiQL there is only two mutation queries are listing(createEmptyCart, placeholderMutation) and it is not allowing to run any other query like generateCustomerToken etc.

So please let me know how can I import these queries to ChromeiQL so that I can use them. Right now it is giving errors likes:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot query field \"generateCustomerToken\" on type \"Mutation\".",
      "category": "graphql",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 7
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the query you type, What is your endpoint you setup?

Comment: I found the issue. Actually the customer schema of magento CE 2.3 (https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/CustomerGraphQl/etc/schema.graphqls) have the type mutation but in magento EE 2.3.0 it is not present.

Comment: glad to here, You may find some graphql related article here http://www.mujahidh.com/what-is-graphql-in-magento2-3-and-how-to-access-it/